Exercise about contact between a curve and a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$
This excercise is taken from do Carmo, Differential geometry of curves and surfaces, section 3.3.
A Curve $C$ and a Surface $S$ have contact of order $\ge n$ in a common point $p$ if there exists a curve on $\bar{C} \subset S$ passing through $p$ such that $C$ and $\bar{C}$ have contact of order $\ge n$.
If $f(x,y,z) = 0$ is a representation of a neighbornhood of $p$ in $S$ and $\alpha(t) = (x(0), y(0), z(0))$ is a parametrization of $C$ in p with $\alpha(0) = p$ prove that $C$ and $S$ have contact of order $\ge n$ if and only if $$f(x(0),y(0),z(0)) = 0,\quad \frac{df}{dt} = \dots = \frac{d^nf}{dt^n} = 0$$
The book doesn't give a definition for the contact of order $\ge n$ of two curves, but i think it means that the derivatives of the parametrizations of the two curves coincide at least up to the $n^{th}$ order.

Showing that the derivatives of $f$ are 0 is easy because $f$ is constant along any curve in the neighborhood.
For the other implication however i have almost no idea

It is not easy to understand this fact easily for a general $f$. It is, instead, really easier to understand the fact for a function of the form $$
g(x,y,z) = z - \varphi(x,y).
$$
Such a (smooth) function describing the same surface $\{f =0\} = \{g =0\}$ necessarily exists by the Implicit Function Theorem.
In this case, the curve $\bar{C}$ is easily described in the following way: if $C$ is parametrised by $\alpha(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$, then $\bar{C}$ can be parametrised by $$
\bar{\alpha}(t) = \big(x(t),y(t),\varphi(x(t),y(t))\big).
$$
This curve satisfies the contact condition: the assumption $(g\circ {\alpha})^{(i)}(0) =0$ for $i = 0,\dotsc , n$ reads $$
z^{(i)}(0) - (\varphi \circ (x,y))^{(i)}(0) =0,
$$ which is the contact condition on the curves $C$ and $\bar{C}$.
The reasoning works for our particular choice of defining function; we can conclude by proving the following result:
Proposition. Given $\alpha(t)$ a smooth curve and $\{f =0\}$ a surface described by a regular equation, the condition $$
(f\circ {\alpha})^{(i)}(0) =0 \qquad \forall\, i = 0,\dotsc , n
$$ does not depend on the smooth, regular function $f$ that we choose to represent the surface.
I found that the proof of this result really is non-trivial. I prove it via an important lemma, which I first met on this site at Local defining functions on real hypersurfaces.. I prove it for the sake of completion.
Lemma. [Smooth Nullstellensatz] Let $f=0$ and $g=0$ be regular equations for the same (hyper)surface. Then, there is a smooth, everywhere non-zero function $h$ such that $f = g h$.
Proof. I prove it for $g(\mathbf{x},z) = z - \varphi(\mathbf{x})$; the general case can be done by combining two of these. Just use the one-variable Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on $f(\mathbf{x},z)$: since $f(\mathbf{x},\varphi(\mathbf{x})) \equiv 0$, you get $$
f(\mathbf{x},z) = \int_{\varphi(\mathbf{x})}^z \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (\mathbf{x},t)\, \mathrm{d}t = (z - \varphi(\mathbf{x})) \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (\mathbf{x},\varphi(\mathbf{x}) + t z)\, \mathrm{d}t.
$$ Hence the function $$
h(\mathbf{x},z) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} (\mathbf{x},\varphi(\mathbf{x}) + t z)\, \mathrm{d}t
$$ solves the equation, and is smooth. The fact that it's never zero follows directly from the assumptions: we prove that $h\ne 0$ holds in the whole space, that is, both on points with $f=0$ and on points with $f\ne 0$.
Of course, when $f\ne 0$ we also have $g\ne 0$, and hence $f = g h$ is uniquely solved by $h = f/g$; on the points of the (hyper)surface, i.e. when $f=g=0$, we know that $f$ is a regular equation, i.e. $\nabla f \ne \mathbf{0}$. But if it were $h=0$, we'd have $$
\mathbf{0} \ne \nabla f = \nabla (g h) = g \nabla h + h \nabla g = 0 \nabla h + 0 \nabla g = \mathbf{0},
$$ contradiction. $\square$
Now we can prove the proposition, by induction on $n$.
$n=0$ is tautological; assume the theorem proved for $n-1$. Assume that $f=0$ and $g=0$ are smooth, regular equations for the same surface; write $f= gh$. Assume that the condition $(f\circ {\alpha})^{(i)}(0) =0$ for $i = 0,\dotsc , n$ holds. By inductive hypothesis, we then already also know that $(g\circ {\alpha})^{(i)}(0) =0$ for $i = 0,\dotsc , n-1$. Call $F = f\circ \alpha$, $G = g \circ \alpha$ and $H = h \circ \alpha$ to simplify notation. Then $$
F^{(n)}(0) = \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n} G(t)H(t) \Big|_{t=0} = G^{(n)}(0) H(0).
$$ The fact that $H(0) = h(\mathbf{0}) \ne 0$ entails the conclusion.
